# How to start one route to another with interval time in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I wanna call route2 from route1 and it should execute interval time, I created below code, is it correct code, write multiple **from** methods, can anyone please give me suggestions?

```
//Route1
  from("timer:repeatcount=1").
    .to("direct:route2 ");
//Route2    
    from("direct:route2").
    from("timer://simpleTimer?period=1000")
    .setBody(simple("Hello from timer at ${header.firedTime}"))
    .to("stream:out");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below you'll find a minimal complete Camel 3 (version 3.4.3) example how to trigger a route (`TimerRoute`) with [Timer](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/timer-component.html) component and how to call another route (`SaveFileRoute`). The example is implemented with Camel [Main](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/others/main.html) module.

The routes use [From](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/from-eip.html) EIP to consume messages from [endpoints](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/endpoint.html) generated by [Timer](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/timer-component.html) and [Direct](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/direct-component.html) components and [To](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/to-eip.html) EIP to produce (or "to send") messages to the consumers.

First the Timer component is used to automatically generate route invocations. This is the starting point of the message flow:

```java
from("timer:exampleTimer?fixedRate=true&period=3s")
```

In the end of the first route the message is forwarded to the second route:

```java
.to("direct:savefile")
```

Next step takes place in the second route where the message is consumed:

```java
from("direct:savefile")
```

Because the second route doesn't forward the message anywhere the message flow ends there.

Note that in the string `"direct:savefile"`:

- `direct` is the type of component generating the endpoint
- `saveFile` is a name that uniquely identifies the endpoint

The complete example:

```java
// https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/others/main.html
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.main.Main;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.configure().addRoutesBuilder(
            new RouteBuilder() {
                public void configure() {
                    from("direct:savefile")
                    .routeId("SaveFileRoute")
                    .log("ROUTE START: body = ${body}")
                    // just logging here
                    // .to("file://outbox")
                    .log("ROUTE END:")
                    ;
                }
            }
        );
        main.configure().addRoutesBuilder(
            new RouteBuilder() {
                public void configure() {
                    // triggers on every 3 seconds
                    // https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/timer-component.html
                    from("timer:exampleTimer?fixedRate=true&period=3s")
                    .routeId("TimerRoute")
                    .log("ROUTE START:")
                    // https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/setBody-eip.html
                    .setBody(constant("HELLO FROM TIMER!"))
                    .to("direct:savefile")
                    .log("ROUTE END:")
                    ;
                }
            }
        );
        main.run(args);
    }
}
```

Example run:

```
$ mvn compile exec:java
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< net.jani-hur:004-timer >-----------------------
[INFO] Building 004-timer 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ 003-timer ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ 003-timer ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:java (default-cli) @ 004-timer ---
[                    App.main()] BaseMainSupport                INFO  Using properties from: classpath:application.properties;optional=true
[                    App.main()] DefaultRoutesCollector         INFO  No additional Camel XML routes discovered from: classpath:camel/*.xml
[                    App.main()] DefaultRoutesCollector         INFO  No additional Camel XML rests discovered from: classpath:camel-rest/*.xml
[                    App.main()] AbstractCamelContext           INFO  Apache Camel 3.4.3 (camel-1) is starting
[                    App.main()] AbstractCamelContext           INFO  StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
[                    App.main()] InternalRouteStartupManager    INFO  Route: SaveFileRoute started and consuming from: direct://savefile
[                    App.main()] InternalRouteStartupManager    INFO  Route: TimerRoute started and consuming from: timer://exampleTimer
[                    App.main()] AbstractCamelContext           INFO  Total 2 routes, of which 2 are started
[                    App.main()] AbstractCamelContext           INFO  Apache Camel 3.4.3 (camel-1) started in 0.031 seconds
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] TimerRoute                     INFO  ROUTE START:
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] SaveFileRoute                  INFO  ROUTE START: body = HELLO FROM TIMER!
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] SaveFileRoute                  INFO  ROUTE END:
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] TimerRoute                     INFO  ROUTE END:
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] TimerRoute                     INFO  ROUTE START:
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] SaveFileRoute                  INFO  ROUTE START: body = HELLO FROM TIMER!
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] SaveFileRoute                  INFO  ROUTE END:
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] TimerRoute                     INFO  ROUTE END:
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] TimerRoute                     INFO  ROUTE START:
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] SaveFileRoute                  INFO  ROUTE START: body = HELLO FROM TIMER!
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] SaveFileRoute                  INFO  ROUTE END:
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] TimerRoute                     INFO  ROUTE END:
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] TimerRoute                     INFO  ROUTE START:
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] SaveFileRoute                  INFO  ROUTE START: body = HELLO FROM TIMER!
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] SaveFileRoute                  INFO  ROUTE END:
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] TimerRoute                     INFO  ROUTE END:
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] TimerRoute                     INFO  ROUTE START:
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] SaveFileRoute                  INFO  ROUTE START: body = HELLO FROM TIMER!
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] SaveFileRoute                  INFO  ROUTE END:
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] TimerRoute                     INFO  ROUTE END:
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] TimerRoute                     INFO  ROUTE START:
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] SaveFileRoute                  INFO  ROUTE START: body = HELLO FROM TIMER!
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] SaveFileRoute                  INFO  ROUTE END:
[read #0 - timer://exampleTimer] TimerRoute                     INFO  ROUTE END:
^C$
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, here how are you calling route2 from route1, in your example is there any relation between route1 and route2, could you please respond?

Comment: @sreekanthjanapati I have updated the answer to give you a little bit more guidance. Unfortunately your question indicates that you don't have a good understanding of the essential Camel concepts. If you don't understand concepts like EIP, component, endpoint and exchange you'll never understand Camel code. Luckily Internet has plenty of introductions explaining the basics ! Unfortunately https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/ is not the best one :(

Comment: @sreekanthjanapati E.g. https://tomd.xyz/camel-routes/ seems to be a good introduction to Camel routes.

Comment: Thanks for your time , my bad i may not explain the question upto you , my main intension is, i have to call savefile router (route2 should call every interval)  TimerRoute (route1) should call only once, exactly reverse case for your example